# OctoberCMS setting

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I try to deploy another webiste in my ubuntu server so I edited my apache setting but my octobercms showed this .What should I try to edit my apache setting to let my website back[image]

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the php code is directly printed shows that you have no handler for php, what you should add.

For example :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php*|phtm|phtml|asp|aspx)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```